# EF Core Owned Entity - OwnsMany + OwnsOne within single Aggregate

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a question/tip regarding the Owned-Entities concept in EF Core 7, which may be helpful for others and help resolve my doubts. This is my first Stack Overflow question, so I apologize in advance for any formatting issues.

Let's consideer an `Document` aggregate root with its versions (`DocumentVersion`).

Goal:

- On `IncrementVersion()` and `DbContext.SaveChanges()` I would like to set `LatestVersionId` in the `Document` table and additionally add this record with corresponding values into the `DocumentVersion` table. It seems to be standard "audit" casus, when we want to update the value, but also track changes.

```
internal class Document
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public List<DocumentVersion> Versions { get; set; } = new();

    public DocumentVersion LatestVersion { get; set; }

    public void IncrementVersison()
    {
        DocumentVersion version = new();

        Versions.Add(version);
        LatestVersion = version;
    }
}

internal class DocumentVersion
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string Version { get; set; };

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; };
}
```

I was able to solve this using Owned-Entity feature with following model configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .OwnsMany(x => x.Versions);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .OwnsOne(x => x.LatestVersion);
}
```

The result was:
[Owned Entity Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t87Zq.png)

Read worked fine and EF Core was able to project `Document` with `LatestVersion` set.

To remmediate the issue with duplicated columns in Documents table I ignored redundant properties:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
    .OwnsOne(x => x.LatestVersion, prop =>
    {
        prop.Ignore(x => x.Version);
        prop.Ignore(x => x.CreatedDate);
    });
```

The code still worked with the same results, but without duplicated values in Documents table.

**UPDATE:** Ignoring properties did not help. The `LatestVersion` was incomplete after load.

Additionally following code was required:

```
public void IncrementVersison()
{
    DocumentVersion version = new();

    Versions.Add(version);
    LatestVersion = version.Clone(); // It cannot be the same reference
}
```

Without it I got:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Cannot save instance of 'Document.Versions#DocumentVersion' because it is an owned entity without any reference to its owner. Owned entities can only be saved as part of an aggregate also including the owner entity.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.PrepareToSave()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.GetEntriesToSave(Boolean cascadeChanges)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__112_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\_Work\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 18
```

GitHub to reproduce - https://github.com/k-mkr/OwnedEntity-Within-AggregateRoot-SO-Question

## Questions:

- Is there any other way or best practice how to handle value update and store historical changes of the same entity within one aggregate root. Property ignore just worked, but it seems to be non-optimal solution if I need to remember about "ignoring" future properties. Writing extensions method `IgnoreExcept` can do the job, but sounds like workaround for a problem.
- Why EF Core worked like that with creating separate column for every property in aggregate root table and why it still worked after "ignoring" the properties
- Why the same reference could not be passed into `LatestVersion` and `Versions` properties. I found the solution in one of Julie Lerman course, but the root cause is still unclear to me.

Comment: Why even have the property LatestVersion? Add a create date and sort the Versions list descending by it and you get your latest version!

Comment: At first glance I see two reasons:
1. No need to populate Versions
2. Single property is not always straight-forward (latest in this case)
This model is sample to illustrate the problem.

Let's consider e.g. currency exchange rate fluctuations.